# How to understand the operation "choose a random subset" in combinatorics?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, measure-theory, discrete-mathematics, additive-combinatorics

Hello I'm reading Tao and Vu's book **additive combinatorics**，and I can not fully convince myself to believe the proof of **Theorem 1.13**. In the proof, they constructed a set by the following way(It seems that I'm not allowed to upload picture now, so I type it down)

> Define a set $B\subset\mathbb{Z}^+$ randomly by requiring the events $n\in B$ (for $n\in \mathbb{Z}^+$) to be jointly independent with probability $\textbf{P}(n\in B)=\min\bigg(C\sqrt{\frac{\log n}{n}},1\bigg)$, where $C$ is a large constant to be chosen later.

Since I've not seen such a method before, I have several questions:

1. If one talks about **randomness**, then there should be a probability space. In the proof they choose a set $B$ **randomly**, what is the probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ here?
2. Relating to the first question, how could I require that events $\{n\in B\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}^+}$ to be jointly independent?
3. Why could I require that events $\{n\in B\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}^+}$ have the assigned probability?

Any comments should be helpful!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWZN5.png

Answer (score 3):

1. There may be several probability spaces.
   Example: when we speak about one coin toss, we may use $\Omega = \{0, 1\}$, $\mathcal{F} = 2^{\Omega}$, $P(0)=p$, $P(1) = 1-p$ with $\xi(\omega) = \omega$ or $\Omega = [0,1]$, $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{B}[0,1]$, $P$ - standard Lebesgue measure,  with $\xi(\omega) = I_{x \in [0,p]}$. Both of them are correct.

In your problem we may put $\Omega_1 = \{ (i_1, i_2, \ldots ) | i_j \in \{ 0; 1\} \}$ and $\mathcal{F} =\sigma$-algebra containing the cylindrical sets. For example, $ w = (1,0,1,1,0, \ldots )$ means that $1 \in B, 2 \notin B, 3 \in B, 4\in B, 5 \notin B, \ldots$.
We also may put $\Omega_2 = [0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$ with corresponding $\sigma$-algebra.

2-3. Put $a(n) = \min\bigg(C\sqrt{\frac{\log n}{n}},1\bigg)$ and define $P( w \in \Omega_1 : w_{i_1} = 1, w_{i_2} = 0, w_{i_3} =1) =a_{i_1} (1-a_{i_2})a_{i_3} $ and so on. It allows us to define a measure on cylindrical $\sigma$-algebra. The existence of such a measure follows from Kolmogorov existence theorem.

Remark:  the explicit form of $\Omega$ is not important in such problems as it doesn't give any useful information.

Comment: Thanks for comment! So you mean that the random set is not exactly a set, it should be viewed as a measurable mapping $B:\Omega\rightarrow 2^{\mathbb{N}}$, each $\omega\in\Omega$ under the mapping $B$ would take a value $B(\omega)\subset\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @Tutukeainie, yes. Consider the next analogy: a random variable is not a number but a mapping. Indeed, if we roll the dice, we may get one of 6 numbers, so random variable is not a number. It's a mapping, and a random set is something like a random variable, but with values at $2^{\mathbb{R}}$. It's called random element in general case.

Comment: I think that in your example $\Omega_1=\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$, $\mathcal{F}$ should not be the power set $2^\mathcal{\Omega_1}$, it is too large. It should be the smallest $\sigma-$ algebra contaning the cylindrical sets?

Comment: @Tutukeainie, indeed, we need only the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing the cylindrical sets. Are you sure that $2^{\Omega_1}$ is bigger?

Comment: I'm not familiar with probability. I remember that for infinite product space, cylindrical $\sigma$-algebra is not the same as the full $\sigma$-algebra (whole subsets).

Comment: @Tutukeainie, you were right, $2^{\Omega}$ is bigger: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2451912/a-sigma-algebra-on-omega-0-1-bbb-n-strictly-smaller-than-2-omega   I edited my answer a bit.